# Call Microservice from another Microservice within Docker

Tags: c#, docker, microservices, docker-for-windows

I created several Microservices in C# that are running on docker in windows, I need to call Microservice from another Microservice so I used this way to call:

```
    [HttpGet("GetOrder/{Object_ID}")]
    public Order GetOrder (int id)
    {
        string Baseurl = "http://189.29.0.100/";
        …..

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            borrowerData = await client.GetStringAsync("api/order/" + Id.ToString());

        }

       …
    }
```

I used the fix IP in Composed file as follows:

```
 orderservice:
    environment:
     - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
   ports:
  - "80"
networks:
  default:
    ipv4_address: 189.29.0.100
```

The problem is when we deploy this project in VM, how to make it work with these Ips?

Comment: You should use a name instead. Like `serviceA`. Then you should use `extra_hosts` in your compose to make host entry for the app's IP to `189.29.0.100`. When deploying to a VM you could use a entry in `/etc/hosts` for the host

Comment: You can create a network with a valid name and use it as a hostname. does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker compose create a virtual network on you host and the services are not routable from outside of docker with those IPs. But inside the virtual network all services can access to each other with their names (`http://otherservice/`).
If you want to access to all deployed microservices on VM you will need a reverse proxy inside your docker compose. For example an nginx service that dispatch request to other services.

Comment: Should each of these microservices have their own docker-compose file? If so, can a virtual network on one docker-compose file have access to another (microroservice with a separate docker-compose file)? I have a similar question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48663545/1632961 if you would like to give your insight

Comment: It's easier to have one compose file for all your stack. Unless it's too big to be managed by one operation team. If you want to scale it out on many physical nodes you may use docker-compose version 3 for swarm mode. Or Kubernetes instead of docker compose.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Bardia that using a docker-compose file is the easiest way to let microservices know the location of each other! Personally, I also use one compose file for all my microservices.

So if you name the service `service-a` in your `docker-compose.yml` file, you will be able to find it by `http://service-a:{port}/path`. This has a huge advantage: you can use the same port on every microservice without worrying about port collision (since DNS is used to resolve the path), this is also crucial for enabling horizontal scaling!

Going one step further, like @Bardia said, add a reverse-proxy instead of starting real chaos with ports on the host machine... I personally like [Traefik](https://traefik.io/), you can configure it by using labels in your service descriptions of the compose file. This also has the advantages for your UI application (if you have one) to access the microservice APIs via relative paths. Thus, you can deploy it anywhere without the necessity to change paths.