# How to implement microservices architecture with docker compose?

Tags: docker, architecture, docker-compose, containers, microservices

I am working on a web application that requires few microservices like a URL shorter, mailer, analytics, etc... Each of these services are implemented as REST api so they can talk to each other. Each of these services have a *docker-compose.yml* file and use containers like nginx, php, mysql, etc… I want these to work as a single system. I don’t want to expose these REST apis to anyone outside of the docker network

My question is how can I combine multiple *docker-compose.yml* files from each service so they work together? Or should I use one big *docker-compose.yml* file to define all the services under one network? Or should I base each of my service only on one container (ubuntu as base and install php, mysql, nginx through Dockerfile) then run them through *docker-compose.yml*, on a shared network?  Or have I misunderstood implementing microservices with Docker?

Answer (score 3):

> how can I combine multiple `docker-compose.yml` files from each service so they work together?

If you choose this path, make sure that your containers attach to the **same network**. You can find information about this case here: [Networking in Compose: Use a pre-existing network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network).

> Or should I use one big `docker-compose.yml` file to define all the services under one network?

It is again up to you to decide if this should be your approach. In this case, you are correct, all the containers can attach to the **default** network that is going to be created. From the same docs:

*Note: Your app’s network is given a name based on the “project name”, which is based on the name of the directory it lives in. You can override the project name with either the `--project-name` flag or the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.*

> Or should I base each of my service only on one container (ubuntu as base and install php, mysql, nginx through Dockerfile)

I am not quite sure, what you mean here exactly...

- if you talk about having all these installed to one container, don't do it. This way you get back to a "monolith" approach.
- if you talk about starting with "ubuntu" as a base and continue by building separate containers for php, mysql, nginx etc, you can do it. But I would suggest you to better use the official images provided by https://hub.docker.com

Comment: What I meant by the "each of my service only on one container" is have a docker file with "FROM ubuntu" then "RUN apt-get install mysql-server php php-mcrypt..." so rather than using multiple containers per service, have one container with all the dependencies installed in it. 

Then I can combine all these single-container services (url shorter, mailer, etc...) with a docker-compose file, in the same network. This method is not monolith, is it?

Comment: You should consider containers as processes. This means that you wouldn't like to have a single container running daemons for apache, mysql, php all-in-one. This is described here as *bloated* vs *lean* containers: [Implementing Separation of Concerns with Docker and Containers](https://www.slideshare.net/jpetazzo/implementing-separation-of-concerns-with-docker-and-containers), slides 32-34.

Comment: To correct myself, this answer [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container) states that *The official docker documentation has moved away from saying "one process" to instead recommending "one concern" per container*.

Comment: @tgogos, would you know why the source code should be separated in a dedicated container like in this [docker-compose](https://github.com/php-microservices/docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) example from the book [PHP Microservices](https://books.google.com.mt/books?id=lLkrDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)?

Comment: Hi @Kwadz! I can't understand what exactly they are trying to achieve with this approach, sorry :-)