# Call Microservice from another Microservice in Docker not working

Tags: c#, docker, microservices, asp.net-core-2.1

I've two microservices in my dockerized application. One is Web Api Project and second is Web MVC application. I want to call web api in mvc application.

Note: I'm using .Net Core 2.1

I'm making call in this way:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var res = await 
                client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:44398/api/values");

                return Ok(res);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

But it's giving this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively refused it
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port,   
CancellationToken cancellationToken)

HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target 
machine actively refused it
WebMVCApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in HomeController.cs, line 27
```

When I making call from browser It's working fine. Even If I use same code without docker and then call the web api from mvc app it working fine. 
I also enabled the CORS:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    } 
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue. I've spend alot of time to fix this but I'm unable to understand what is the issue.

I also read answer from this question on stackoverflow.

[Call Microservice from another Microservice within Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370014/call-microservice-from-another-microservice-within-docker)

But I can't understand how I can use just api name as url as explained in this answer. when I use api name in url like this:

```
https://catalogapi:44398/api/values
```

It produce this error:

```
SocketException: No such host is known
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: How are you launching the containers?  They need to be on the same Docker network for the DNS lookup to work; if they’re started from the same `docker-compose.yml` file this should happen automatically for you.

Comment: Yes @DavidMaze all containers started from the same `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Sharing contents of `docker-compose.yml` would help with debugging the issue. Full [mre] would be much preferable though.

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose creates a virtual network on your host, and the services with those IPs are not routable from outside of Docker.

Services can communicate with one another using their names `http://running-service/`.

We can use a Docker compose file to initialize details such as service name and use it to call the other microservice, for example, `http://running-service-1:port/`.